# XOR EQUALITY-codechef May 2021 long challenge

Tags: python-3.x

#I am not getting what's wrong in this code to get a TIME LIMIT EXEEDED error

```
t = int(input())
for j in range(t):
    n = int(input())-1
    count = 0
    res = (2**n)%((10**9)+7)
    print(res)
```

Comment: What were the inputs provided that results in `time limit exceeded` error? And what is the use of count?

Comment: Count has no use I just forgot to remove that. I don't know what were the provided inputs https://www.codechef.com/MAY21C/problems/XOREQUAL you can refer to this link to understand the problem.